# Calculate Display Resolution (Width &Height)

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

i want to calculate the display resulution in Width/Height, this ratio is always 0.75
example: 768/1024=0,75

I only have the value of MegaPixel 6,1 MP

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not Mathematica:

```
width*height=megapixels
3*width*height=3*megapixels
3*width=4*height
4*height*height=3*megapixels
height^2=3*megapixels/4
height=sqrt(3*megapixels)/2
width=4/3*height
```

you'll probably have errors as 6.1 MP is not accurate